# Is there a way to have VS Code add TypeScript triple slash directives to the top of the TS file in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

When I use C# with VS Code, if I reference a class whose namespace I have not yet included at the top of the file, a light bulb "Quick Fix" menu appears offering to add that namespace to the top of the file. When I click it, `using My.Foo.Namespace;` is added to the top of the file, and the reference is resolved by the compiler.

[image: VS Code add "using" statement in the C# Quick Fix menu]

Is there a way to do something similar with TypeScript [triple slash directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)? For example, in the following screenshot I would like to add `/// <reference path="../../core/utils/SomeModule.ts" />` to the top. Unfortunately, I have to type such references manually, which is error prone and time consuming.

[image: No Quick Fix light bulb for TypeScript]

Is there any Visual Studio Code command, extension or task that that can generate those for me on demand? It's a feature I use constantly in C#, and I miss it dearly in TypeScript.